# Why does my ListView not display the list of items?

Tags: java, android, listview, listactivity, simpleadapter

I am trying to display my list of alarms in the ListActivity but it does not work. There rows appear but there is no text visible. I'm not sure if it's retrieving the data from the HashMap and inserting into the rows correctly.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_list);
        List<Alarm> list;
        Database db = new Database(AlarmListActivity.this);
        list = db.getAllAlarms();
        
        List<HashMap<String, String>> alarmMap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (Alarm alarm: list) {
           HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
           map.put(Integer.toString(alarm.getID()), alarm.toString());
           alarmMap.add(map);
        }
        
        if(!list.isEmpty() && list != null)
        {
            System.out.println("inside list");
            System.out.println(list);
            
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    AlarmListActivity.this,
                    alarmMap,
                    R.layout.list_item, 
                    new String[] { "id", "hour"},
                    new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.time});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
      
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(AlarmListActivity.this, "No Alarms Set",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    }
```

[image: List]

This is what I get. You can vaguely see the lines of each row. But there is no text or anything. All the System.out.println() work as expected which print out the HashMap. It's just nothing is being displayed in the list. I've even added: `android:text="Testing"` to no avail

Comment: Does your `Alarm` class have its own `toString()` method?

Comment: Yes, you can see that I'm calling it above inside the for loop. However, I am unable to automatically call toString by just calling the alarm variable, instead I have to explicitly call it: alarm.toString()

Comment: OK. May be I'm missing something here. Could you please post the exact results you're getting vs. what you expect to see?

Comment: Do you get this output: `System.out.println("inside list");` ?

Comment: Set the text in your layout to a color, like red and see if it appears. If it's still invisible then post your layout file.

Comment: Please post activity_alarm_list.xml and list_item.xml